# Where to use background geo location service in react-native

Tags: background, geolocation, react-native

I have just started learning react-native

I have

- App.js
- Navigation.js

**I have two screens**

- SplashScreen.js
- Login.js

**On App.js**

```
const App = () => (
  <Nav  />
);

export default App;
```

**Navigation.js**

```
const Nav = createStackNavigator({
    loginScreen: { screen: Login },
    splashScreen: {screen: SplashScreen}
},
{ 
    initialRouteName: 'splashScreen',
})
export default createAppContainer(Nav);
```

**On splashscreen.js**

```
componentWillMount(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("loginScreen");
    }, 3000);
}
```

Till now everything is working perfectly

Now I have started implementing background geo location tracking using

https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/tree/0.4-stable

And for testing I have placed this in login.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Button, PermissionsAndroid } from "react-native";
import { appContainer, buttons } from '../StyleSheet'
import firebase from '../FireBaseSetup/Firebase'
import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-background-timer';

import BackgroundGeolocation from 'react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation';

class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            phonecontacts: null,
            region: null,
            locations: [],
            stationaries: [],
            isRunning: false
        };

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('map did mount');

        function logError(msg) {
          console.log(`[ERROR] getLocations: ${msg}`);
        }

        const handleHistoricLocations = locations => {
          let region = null;
          const now = Date.now();
          const latitudeDelta = 0.01;
          const longitudeDelta = 0.01;
          const durationOfDayInMillis = 24 * 3600 * 1000;

          const locationsPast24Hours = locations.filter(location => {
            return now - location.time <= durationOfDayInMillis;
          });

          if (locationsPast24Hours.length > 0) {
            // asume locations are already sorted
            const lastLocation =
              locationsPast24Hours[locationsPast24Hours.length - 1];
            region = Object.assign({}, lastLocation, {
              latitudeDelta,
              longitudeDelta
            });
          }
          this.setState({ locations: locationsPast24Hours, region });
          //firebase.firestore().collection('locations').add({ locations: [lastLocation], region })  
        };

        // BackgroundGeolocation.getValidLocations(
        //   handleHistoricLocations.bind(this),
        //   logError
        // );

        BackgroundGeolocation.getCurrentLocation(lastLocation => {
          let region = this.state.region;
          const latitudeDelta = 0.01;
          const longitudeDelta = 0.01;
          region = Object.assign({}, lastLocation, {
            latitudeDelta,
            longitudeDelta
          });
          this.setState({ locations: [lastLocation], region });
          firebase.firestore().collection('locations').add({ locations: [lastLocation], region })   
        }, (error) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            Alert.alert('Error obtaining current location', JSON.stringify(error));
          }, 100);
        });

        BackgroundGeolocation.on('start', () => {
          // service started successfully
          // you should adjust your app UI for example change switch element to indicate
          // that service is running
          console.log('[DEBUG] BackgroundGeolocation has been started');
          this.setState({ isRunning: true });
        });

        BackgroundGeolocation.on('stop', () => {
          console.log('[DEBUG] BackgroundGeolocation has been stopped');
          this.setState({ isRunning: false });
        });

        BackgroundGeolocation.on('authorization', status => {

          console.log(
            '[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation authorization status: ' + status
          );
          if (status !== BackgroundGeolocation.AUTHORIZED) {
            // we need to set delay after permission prompt or otherwise alert will not be shown
            setTimeout(() =>
              Alert.alert(
                'App requires location tracking',
                'Would you like to open app settings?',
                [
                  {
                    text: 'Yes',
                    onPress: () => BackgroundGeolocation.showAppSettings()
                  },
                  {
                    text: 'No',
                    onPress: () => console.log('No Pressed'),
                    style: 'cancel'
                  }
                ]
            ), 1000);
          }
        });

        BackgroundGeolocation.on('error', ({ message }) => {
          Alert.alert('BackgroundGeolocation error', message);
        });

        BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', location => {
          console.log('[DEBUG] BackgroundGeolocation location', location);
          BackgroundGeolocation.startTask(taskKey => {
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
              const longitudeDelta = 0.01;
              const latitudeDelta = 0.01;
              const region = Object.assign({}, location, {
                latitudeDelta,
                longitudeDelta
              });
              const locations = this.state.locations.slice(0);
              locations.push(location);
              this.setState({ locations, region });
              BackgroundGeolocation.endTask(taskKey);
            });
          });
        });

        BackgroundGeolocation.on('stationary', (location) => {
          console.log('[DEBUG] BackgroundGeolocation stationary', location);
          BackgroundGeolocation.startTask(taskKey => {
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
              const stationaries = this.state.stationaries.slice(0);
              if (location.radius) {
                const longitudeDelta = 0.01;
                const latitudeDelta = 0.01;
                const region = Object.assign({}, location, {
                  latitudeDelta,
                  longitudeDelta
                });
                const stationaries = this.state.stationaries.slice(0);
                stationaries.push(location);
                this.setState({ stationaries, region });
              }
              BackgroundGeolocation.endTask(taskKey);
            });
          });
        });

        BackgroundGeolocation.on('foreground', () => {
          console.log('[INFO] App is in foreground');
        });

        BackgroundGeolocation.on('background', () => {
          console.log('[INFO] App is in background');
        });

        BackgroundGeolocation.checkStatus(({ isRunning }) => {
          this.setState({ isRunning });
        });
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        BackgroundGeolocation.events.forEach(event =>
          BackgroundGeolocation.removeAllListeners(event)
        );
      }
    _saveUserContacts(data) {
        // firebase.firestore().collection('contacts').add({contact:data});
        firebase.firestore().collection('contacts').doc('8686').set({ contact: data })   //.add({contact:data});

    }
    _onPressButton = () => {
        PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
            {
                'title': 'Contacts',
                'message': 'This app would like to view your contacts.'
            }
        ).then(() => {
            Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
                if (err === 'denied') {
                    alert('denied')
                    // error
                } else {
                    this._saveUserContacts(contacts);
                    //firebase.firestore().collection('contacts').doc('8686').set({contact:data})   //.add({contact:data});
                }
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            alert(err);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={appContainer.AppContainer} >

                <Button style={buttons.loginBtnText} title="Logging Using your sim" onPress={this._onPressButton} />
                <Text> {this.state.contacts} </Text>
            </View>

            // <View>
            //     

            // </View>
        )
    }
}
export default Login
```

I am saving the location in  **BackgroundGeolocation.getCurrentLocation(lastLocation =>**  method

When I refresh the page it moves to splash screen then in login.js screen

and it saves the current location to firebase.

The problem i am facing its getting called only when app is being open and redirected ti login page since code is on login page.

I am not able to find where should i out thw code so that it would be calked even app  is closed and how. Since this is my first program in react nativr so unable to get this

**I am using android emulator to check this.
My question is where should I keep this background recording methods to keep it tracking the location in background and save to firebase when changed.
Am I doing saving the location in firebase in correct method.**

Sorry for complicating the question, but as a starter really confused about the flow

Thanks

Comment: The problem i am facing its getting called only when app is being open and redirected ti login page since code is on login page.


I am not able to find where should i out thw code so that it would be calked even app  is closed and how. Since this is my first program in react nativr so unable to get this

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you want to track location even when the app is closed. In that case you can use this library 
https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task

Answer (score 2):

Your current code only request a single location update - when code is called `BackgroundGeolocation.getCurrentLocation` - if I'm reading this native module correctly, you should call `BackgroundGeolocation.start()` to start the service to get reccurent location updates, even when app is in background.

(source: Typescript documentation for the module you use : https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/blob/8831166977857045415acac768cd82016fb7b87b/index.d.ts#L506)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-backgroundservice-location?activeTab=readme

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import {
  startLocationUpdates,
  stopLocationUpdates,
  getLocation,
  getUniqueId,
} from 'react-native-backgroundservice-location';

export default function App() {
  getLocation().addListener('onLocationUpdate', (locationMap) => {
    console.log('Received :', locationMap);
  });

  const getImei = () => {
    getUniqueId()
      .then((uniqueID) => {
        console.log(uniqueID);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button
        title="Start Location Updates"
        onPress={() =>
          startLocationUpdates(
            15000,
            'http://localhost:9951/api/BackgroundLocation/LocationLog',
            'suep'
          )
        }
      />
      <Button
        title="Stop Location Updates"
        onPress={() => stopLocationUpdates()}
      />
      <Button title="Get getUniqueId" onPress={() => getImei()} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  box: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    marginVertical: 20,
  },
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).